# function definition in eval

Tags: python, eval, pyjamas

I try to define a function with a variable name.

Names are retrieved from a database. For every name I want to define a button and have separate handling:

```
title=['BNL','CE']
for i in range(0,len(title)):
    panelvpu.add(Button(title[i]))


for i in range(0,len(title)):
    eval('def onButtonClick'+title[i]+'(self, event):')
    eval('    Window.alert("Yes")')
```

The button definition is ok, but the handling of the event in the defined function gives an error

```
im1 SyntaxError: at index 4 in "def onMenu1Item1(self): 
Window.alert("Item 1 selected")": expected ';', got 'onMenu1Item1'
```

After feedback I changed this to

```
    title=['BNL','CE']
    for t in title : panelvpu.add(Button(t))

for t in title:        
    def_code = "print t"
    exec(def_code)
```

Just to get the feeling; under python this works fine. 
But I use pyjamas and the last code does rais the error stating

```
 im1 TypeError: iter is undefined
```

It appears that pyjamas is not supporting eval() and exec() yet.

Richard

Comment: That doesn't look like separate handling to me...

Comment: Looks like you're trying to make a function factory for callback commands; good thought, but there are better tools that Python gives you to do this.

Comment: What is a Button? How is the event handler associated with the Button? It looks like you're trying to write a free function, but expecting it to behave like a method that belongs to the Button instance.

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of problems here:

1) `eval` is for evaluating an expression, not executing statements.

2) `exec` would need the entire function in one `exec`, not split onto separate lines as you have it.

3) There are much easier ways to create functions, depending on what you want to have in the body.  Tell us about what you really want to do.

4) Your loop is much simpler as: `for t in title: blah blah t`.